# can I take pills before food?

Tags: medications, digestion, stomach, time-of-day

Some medicine is required to take with food. This [question](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/4525/how-much-food-is-necessary-to-buffer-the-stomach-when-taking-medicine) asked how much food you need to take.

But I'm interested if you can take pills and then eat later (20-30 min).

Is it considered that you take pills with food or it's too long and food should be taken exactly the same moment?

Comment: It's not so crucial that you have to time them exactly, but the closer in time the better. 20-30 minutes is stretching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are referring to taking them with a meal (so in a real world sense you'd take them right after you sit down to eat).  I'd suggest taking them as prescribed.  Not taking your medicine with food can affect the bioavailability / absorption of your medicine. Can get a sick feeling too if taken on an empty stomach.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].